# clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, error-handling, clang, vuforia

I just exported my Unity project using Vuforia to Xcode and I get that error. However, I didn't always have that error when exporting my Vuforia based game on to Xcode and then my iPad. I recently downloaded a new version of Vuforia and I think that's when things went wrong. Any ideas of how I could be getting this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel very lost right now